# The locus of points with respect to the ellipse.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, locus

The chord of contact of the point $$(x_1,y_1)$$ with respect to the ellipse $$b^2x^2+a^2y^2=a^2b^2$$ cuts the axes at $L$ and $M$. If the locus of the mid-point of $LM$ is the circle $$x^2+y^2=1$$, find the locus of $(x_1,y_1)$

**MY APPROACH**

Equation of chord of contact is
$$b^2xx_1+a^2yy_1=a^2b^2\tag{1}$$
$\implies$
$\frac{x}{\left(\frac{a^2}{x_1}\right)}+\frac{y}{\left(\frac{b^2}{y_1}\right)}=1$

Points where $(1)$ cuts the x-axes are $$L\left(\frac{a^2}{x_1},0\right)$$ $$M\left(0,\frac{b^2}{y_1}\right)$$
Mid-point $G(h,k)$ of chord $LM$

$$G(h,k)=\left(\frac{a^2}{2x_1},\frac{b^2}{2y_1}\right)\tag{2}$$

Locus of $(2)$ is given as
$$x^2+y^2=1\tag{3}$$

Then,$(2)$ must satisfy $(3)$
$$\implies\left(\frac{a^2}{2x_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b^2}{2y_1}\right)^2=1$$
$$\implies a^4y_1^2+b^4x_1^2=4x_1^2y_1^2$$

In general $x_1=x$ and $y_1=y$
$$\therefore a^4y^2+b^4x^2=4x^2y^2$$ is the required locus.

**[1]** My doubt starts from $(3)$ to the final step

Is it OK how I found the locus by generalizing $x_1$ and $y_1$ as $x$ and $y$ instead of eliminating them via a certain substitution?

**[2]** If **[1]** is OK and my whole approach is correct. Could I have reached to the solution by a different approach?.

*I appreciate your attention and contribution*

Comment: You approach is correct. Why do you have doubts?

Comment: My doubt was on the way I eliminated $x_1$ and $y_1$ by simply renaming them into $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Comment: I would do the same and actually cannot imagine how else it can be done.

Comment: I appreciate your contribution. I am glad my approach is correct. I am happy and my doubt is cleared.